# I want to limit an image to 16 colors, but ONLY colors from a specific larger set of colors

Tags: image, colors, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert images to a very specific color scheme, and I have an image that consists of 6684 unique colors:

[image: Color Image]

I want to specifically ONLY use colors from this image, but it's too big to use as a color palette (limited to 256).

In addition to this, any images I convert should have a MAX of 16 indexed colors. (EG: Any image I convert should have only 16 colors that it can display like it's a 4 bit image, and all of these 16 colors must be colors that are also present in the image I have posted above.)

Is it possible to do this in imagemagick?

Comment: Is dithering allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the image you provide is called `palette.png`, I think you want to remap all the colours in an input image to that palette, and then do a colour reduction based on nearest neighbour interpolation down to 16 colours which will give you a command like this:

```
magick +dither input.png -remap palette.png -interpolate nearest -colors 16 result.png
```

If this is not what you want, you can debug the above by breaking it down into steps and looking at the partial results:

```
magick +dither input.png -remap palette.png partial.png
```

And:

```
magick partial.png -interpolate nearest -colors 16 result.png
```

---

You may want to experiment with replacing `+dither` by `-dither Riemersma`  or by `-dither FloydSteinberg`.

Note that using a *"Nearest Neighbour"* interpolation avoids introducing any new colours into an image - it just uses the nearest neighbour from the existing image rather than averaging or calculating new pixels.